# Accessing ID inside decider and worker in AWS SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-swf

I am working and AWS SWF and wanted to create a workflow such than I can pass an ID during starting of execution and be able to access that in my decider and activity worker.

I am not able to find any documentation related to that.
I am implementing workers and deciders in python using BOTO library.

Answer (score 0):

You actually cannot create a workflow execution without specifying a `workflowId` according to the documentation of [start_workflow_execution](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/swf.html#SWF.Client.start_workflow_execution) method.

Comment: Curious, how do I get the status of an execution if I have the workflowId and runId  of the workflow execution?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_DescribeWorkflowExecution.html